# Change link color onclick without preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I need change the color of the link if clicked.

If I use `event.preventDefault();` color is applied permanently but the link doesn't work, then the uri isn't passed and then I can't use `$_GET['route']` since I using mod_rewrite to redirect all uri's to this `$_GET` var. `^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1`

If i don't use the event.preventDefault the link works and the section changes, but the addClass is only applied WHILE i'am clicking, then dissapears...

How I can get both behaviours ? Be able to pass the URI (HREF), and to permanently change the color `onClick` ?

html:

```
<a href="./section">Section</a>
```

css:

```
.active { color: #f00; }
```

Jquery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in `doc ready` there is no need to specify any `.click()` event:

### try the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cmwt8/

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.href; // url should be this way 'http://aaa.com/page/section'
    var link = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // then you get here 'section'
    $('[href*="' + link + '"]').addClass("active"); // if found add the class
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works. You're right, Is easier to add the class after the event occurs :$

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to do any JavaScripting. You just need the following CSS

```
a:visited { color: #f00; }
```

Edit. If you only want to target specific links to be highlighted, add a class to the `<a>` link ie

HTML

```
<a class="sticky" href="./section">Section</a>
```

CSS

```
a.sticky:visited  { color: #f00; }
```

That way, only the hyperlinks you want to stay sticky will have the colour applied

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    $('#elementID').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        window.location.href="./section";
    });
```

And update the href of anchor tag as "#". i.e.

```
<a href="#"
```

Comment: How would `.active` class be added at a new page with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because after you've been redirected to a page. all objects classes will reset.

but you can put this on your `$(document).ready()`

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
$('a[href$="' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Now what this does is as the page load example you have

`<a href="hello.php">test</a>`

as the page load. The `page` will get your last url ex. `www.mysite.com/hello.php`
and will find an `a` will matching url and add certain class.

Comment: It happens in a template page, the nav links doesn't redirect or reload the page, I'm using mod_rewrite and PHP includes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this because its natural behavior of click.

if you use `preventDefault()` that means you are forcing natural behavior to work as per your rules.

anyways you can still have some alternatives.

1. ```
   $('a').on('click', function(event)
   {
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       event.preventDefault
       $(this).addClass("active");
       window.location = href;
   });
   ```

now at this point your redirection will come to action so you don't have way to get if link color is already been changed on previous click call so `session` can help you.

Inside `click event` make ajax call and just set `session variable` now after page redirect check for session that you have set `during ajax call` then add class if `session` already there.